# Get the removed elements from an observable array

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

```
vm.caseRecords.remove(function (item) { return item.AppealStatusCd == vm.selectedAppealStatusCd() });
```

The above statement does remove items from the caseRecords observableArray and also updates it. How can I get the elements which were removed ?

Answer (score 1):

The result of `remove` is the removed items, so you can just say:

```
var removedItems = vm.caseRecords.remove(function (item) { return item.AppealStatusCd == vm.selectedAppealStatusCd() });
```

Comment: That's what I did but I found that it contains 0 elements where as the items are getting removed from the collection.

Comment: maybe try to reproduce in jsFiddle. `.remove` will return any items that were removed.  could be something else going on.

Comment: My mistake. The property AppealStatusCd  is not in the item but in the navigationproperty present in item.